# Problems connecting self hosted IR in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I already have a self hosted IR set up for one of the on-prem servers.
I was wanting to use the same IR for another on prem server, however, i receive this error.

[image: check error in this image]

Could someone please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the [Remote access from intranet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#enable-remote-access-from-an-intranet) settings from the settings tab of the integration runtime of the first node? Make sure the status is enabled.

Comment: Hi @ray - where would i find the settings of the first IR node? (sorry ive just joined a new company and the person who set this up has left).

Comment: It should be the "one of the on-prem servers" that you mentioned. You should be able to locate the IP address of the server in ADF integration runtime page like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#scale-up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the node which you want to use has been added later in the existing IR and it is not configured for remote access from intranet.

You need to install the Self-Hosted IR again, add new node and configure the remote access from intranet for this new node.

Please go through [this article](https://www.techtalkcorner.com/self-hosted-integration-runtime-cluster/) and follow the given steps to configure new node.

Comment: Thnx all sorted now.